# Select Most Frequent from Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table like;

```
ID | Winner   | Loser    | WinningCaster | LosingCaster
0  | Player A | Player B | Warcaster A   | Warcaster B
1  | Player A | Player B | Warcaster C   | Warcaster A
2  | Player C | Player D | Warcaster A   | Warcaster B
```

etc..

With various values for Player, and Warcaster. 
WinningCaster / LosingCaster is a finite namelist, and I want to make a query that will find me which name occurs the most often, across both columns, both with and without a particular player entry. 
IE Player A should return WarcasterA with 2, and an overall Query should return WarcasterA with 3.

So far I've only been able to get the most frequent from either column, not from both, with the following;

```
SELECT 
    ID, Winner, Loser, CasterWinner, Count(CasterWinner) AS Occ
FROM 
    `Games`
GROUP BY 
    CasterWinner
ORDER BY 
    Occ DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: the column names that you have in the query is not consistent with the names you have in the table, so it is a bit confusing to see which column you are trying to group by. You can try doing a union all of the winningCaster and Losing Caster Columns and then write your group by query on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`:

```
select caster, count(*)
from ((select casterwinner as caster from games
      ) union all
      (select casterloser from games
      )
     ) c
group by caster
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: That would be it, Thanks.